# Delay in closing PowerShell window when started via Start-Process with Admin rights

Tags: powershell, admin, uac, privileges

Code (not my actual code but it also produces the same behaviour):

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole(`
    [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
    Write-Warning "The script tries to re-run itself using Administrator privileges.";
    try {
        Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) -Verb runAs;
    }
    catch [InvalidOperationException] {
        Write-Warning "You canceled the privilege request. This script WON'T WORK, please re-run it!";
        Read-Host;
        Exit;
    }
    Exit;
}

# Here comes the code which will be run if started with Admin rights
Read-Host;
```

When I accept Windows UAC and I close the appearing PS window via `[X]`, the window disappears in 3-5 seconds instead of closing directly!

I'm using **Windows 8** Pro 64-bit.

Comment: On my Windows Seven the window disappears immediatly. Your code works as expected.

Comment: @JPBlanc So the problem is only occuring on (my?) Windows 8!

Comment: I also see that delay on my Windows 7 machine.

Comment: @DavidBrabant Good to hear that. Are you using the 32 or 64-bit version?

Comment: I don't want to jump to conclusions but maybe it's a 64-bit problem. @JPBlanc Do you use the 32-bit version?

Comment: Something funny: if I just type Start-Process PowerShell -runas from a PowerShell prompt and give appropriate credentials, I can close down the started powershell without delay.

Comment: @DavidBrabant Interesting, I've got the same behaviour on my machine. I think it has also something to do with `Read-Host`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Read-Host` issue. It doesn't affect only 64-bit OS's, I just verified on both x86 and x64 Windows 7 Pro. To reproduce, simply run `Read-Host` at any PowerShell console and close the window.

UPDATE:

I just tested on various versions of Windows and bit-ness, and I'm finding that the resuluts are not consistent. `Read-Host` seems to behave differently sometimes from run to run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which OS and version of PS are you using?

Comment: Win7 x64 w/ PowerShell v3 CTP2 (I really need to update that) and Win7 x86 w/ PowerShell v2. Also see updates above.

Comment: Thanks for your research! I've opened a Microsoft Connect ticket here: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/776422/delay-in-closing-ps-window-when-using-read-host#tabs Maybe, you can post your details there?

Comment: Sure, if I get a chance I'm going to try to get a better breakdown on how it behaves on each platform.